# Interactively Disable the Entry Box in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

My code has two entry boxes one for pizza and the other one is for sandwich. If the user starts typing in the pizza entry box the sandwich box should be disabled and the user cannot type in it. If the user starts typing in the sandwich box then the pizza entry box should be disabled and they cannot type in it. I would like the box to be disabled before the user clicks submit. I have found this answer to be the most similar to what I am looking for and it does the job but I would like to have the same effect before clicking the submit button. [Text] ([Python tkinter disable the button until all the fields are filled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687124/python-tkinter-disable-the-button-until-all-the-fields-are-filled))

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")

pizza = tk.StringVar()
sandwich = tk.StringVar()

def click():
    pizza = pizza_lunch.get()
    sandwich = pie_lunch.get()

pizza_label = tk.Label(root, text='pizza')
pizza_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=pizza)
sandwich_label = tk.Label(root, text='sandwich')
sandwich_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=sandwich)
button = tk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=click)


pizza_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
pizza_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
sandwich_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
sandwich_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
button.grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()

**** modified version ****
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")


pizza = tk.DoubleVar()
sandwich = tk.DoubleVar()

def click(event):
    if pizza.get() != '':
        sandwich_entry.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        pizza_entry.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    if sandwich.get() != '':
        pizza_entry.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        sandwich_entry.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    if pizza.get() == '' and sandwich.get() == "":
        sandwich_entry.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        pizza_entry.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    print("price: " + str(pizza))
    print("price: " + str(sandwich))

pizza_label = tk.Label(root, text='pizza')
pizza_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=pizza)
pizza_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', click)
sandwich_label = tk.Label(root, text='sandwich')
sandwich_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=sandwich)
sandwich_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', click)
button = tk.Button(root, text='Submit',)


pizza_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
pizza_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
sandwich_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
sandwich_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
button.grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

we can make the requirement by binding method, I have some code to your, See if usefull

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")

pizza = tk.StringVar()
sandwich = tk.StringVar()


def click(event):
    if pizza.get() != '':
        sandwich_entry.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        pizza_entry.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    if sandwich.get() != '':
        pizza_entry.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        sandwich_entry.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    if pizza.get() == '' and sandwich.get() == "":
        sandwich_entry.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        pizza_entry.config(state=tk.NORMAL)


pizza_label = tk.Label(root, text='pizza')
pizza_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=pizza)
pizza_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', click)
sandwich_label = tk.Label(root, text='sandwich')
sandwich_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=sandwich)
sandwich_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', click)
button = tk.Button(root, text='Submit',)


pizza_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
pizza_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
sandwich_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
sandwich_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
button.grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It partially does what I am looking for but the button doesn't work afterwards and I would like the button to be able to work and print user input for the doublevar price. I have tried modifying the code.